# Reverse-engineer regex pattern to find number of tokens and length of expected matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

To validate some fields in my forms, I need to find the number of tokens specified by a particular regular expression, as well as the length of the matches specified by that regex. For instance,

1. With pattern `[0-9]{3},[0-9]{2}`, I need to find 5 for length and 2 for number of tokens.
2. With pattern `[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}`, I need to find 8 for length and 3 for number of tokens.

Can anyone point a direction to do this?

Comment: FYI Kleber, added sample js code and an online demo to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you did not ask to solve this with regex, we will. A regex operating on a regex! Is that regex-square?

At first blush, the task sounds complex. Do we need to write a regex engine to parse your exprssions?

Fortunately, if your quantifiers are all inside `{curlies}`, there is a simple solution. If we match all the numbers between curlies, the number of matches will be the number of tokens, and the length will be the sum of the matches.

**Our simple Regex**

```
{(\d+)}
```

**Okay, but how do we implement this in code?**

Here is a complete script that outputs the number of tokens and the length. See the result of the [online demo](http://js.do/code/38693).

```
<script>
var subject = '[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}';
var regex = /{(\d+)}/g;
var group1Caps = [];
var match = regex.exec(subject);

// Place Group 1 captures in an array
while (match != null) {
    if( match[1] != null ) group1Caps.push(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(subject);
}

// How many tokens are there?
document.write("*** Number of Tokens ***<br>");
document.write(group1Caps.length);

// What length are the expected matches?
var counter = 0;
document.write("<br>*** Length of Expected Matches ***<br>");
if (group1Caps.length > 0) {
   for (key in group1Caps) counter += parseInt(group1Caps[key]);
   }
document.write(counter,"<br>")   
</script>
```